# Defining a business month: first Sunday of a month until first Saturday of next month

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, calendar

I have a table with a timestamp field.  In **Postgresql**, I have to define a 'business month' as between the first Sunday of the current month until first Saturday of the following month (eg. 2014-04-06 until 2014-05-03 will be 'April 2014').

I'm not quite sure where to begin.  What I have so far is getting the first Sunday from [this forum post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1010974-338-1.aspx) (with T-SQL).

```
--first sunday of this month....
-1=sunday,-2=saturday,-3-friday etc
SELECT
datename(dw,dateadd(dd,-1,DATEADD(wk, 
DATEDIFF(wk,0,dateadd(dd,7-datepart(day,getdate()),getdate())), 0))),
dateadd(dd,-1,DATEADD(wk, 
DATEDIFF(wk,0,dateadd(dd,7-datepart(day,getdate()),getdate())), 0))
```

I will probably have to build a calendar table and manually define the months.  But I would like to explore other solutions.

Comment: No other solutions will be better than a calendar table.

Comment: I would very strongly recommend a calendar table as well. When you start dealing with complex date manipulation, it's very easy to screw up your logic and not notice it until months (or even years) after you went into production. Leap years are an especially common source of errors. If it were me, I'd definitely create a calendar table for this. It'll be a lot more straight forward than handling the dates with logical expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d23a9/1)

The function

```
create or replace function business_month("month" date)
returns table (first_day date, last_day date) as $$

    with first_month_day as (
        select date_trunc('month', month)::date as first_day
    ), first_business_day as (
        select
            first_day
            + (extract(dow from first_day)::int > 0)::int * 7
            - extract(dow from first_day)::int
            as first_day
        from first_month_day
    ), first_next_month_day as (
        select (first_day + interval '1 month')::date as first_day
        from first_month_day
    ), last_business_day as (
        select
            first_day
            + 6
            - extract(dow from first_day)::int
            as last_day
        from first_next_month_day
    )
    select
        (select first_day from first_business_day) as first_day,
        (select last_day from last_business_day) as last_day
    ;
$$ language sql stable;
```

Test it

```
select
    to_char(d, 'YYYY Month') as month,
    to_char(first_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD Day') as first_day,
    to_char(last_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD Day') as last_day
from
    generate_series ('2010-01-01'::date, '2014-12-31', '1 month') g (d)
    ,
    business_month(d::date)
;
```